# javascript substring method support for interger - chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, substring, keyword

When I try to assign number value to JavaScript keyword name as like below

```
var a="12345";
var b=a.substring(1,3)
console.log(b);
var name=12345;
var y=name.substring(1,3)
console.log(y);
```

I excepted it to throw the type error, but it produces the same output for variable b and name.

I'm aware that keywords should not be used as variable, still curious to know how it works.

Comment: JS does not care about the type means not strongly typed, so when you write name.substring , js does not know if its a string,int or object.
at run time its just parse it to  string and do the function.
the same is true when you try to add 1+"123", it wil lgive you 1123 not error

Comment: That is why now a days people use typescript to avoid such scenarios.

Comment: `name` is `window.name` which is always a string. @Atul you can't use substring on a Number-typed variable. Note that using `let` instead of `var` would allow you to redefine that variable.

Comment: @Jeto the question is why its not throwing an error, that what i was explaining.

Comment: @Atul If you replace `name` with anything else in his 4th line you'll get an error. The reason it's not throwing one is because `var name = 12345` does not create an integer variable because it overwrites `window.name` which is a string (and has to be one).

Comment: @Jeto understood , thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` refers to [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name), a string (which looks to be enforced by browsers).

When you write `var name = 12345;` you basically overwrite it (due to how `var` works, see [differences betwen `var` and `let`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/965834)).

Since `window.name` must hold a string, it's therefore converted to `'12345'` internally.